# What does Perl return from a subroutine when no return statement is encountered?

Tags: perl

*I encountered this today and thought it prudent to post a Q&A as I couldn't find anything similar.

Feel free to vote-to-close if you find a duplicate of this question.*

---

The following subroutine conditionally [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html)s output; I consider it "clumsy" because it isn't explicit about what is returned to the caller when the conditional is not satisfied:

```
sub is_multiple_of_three {

    my ( $value ) = @_ ;
    return "$value is a multiple of 3"
      unless $value % 3;
}
```

A quick rewrite makes short work of clarifying the (more graceful) subroutine's intended behaviour under all circumstances:

```
sub is_multiple_of_three { 

    my ( $value ) = @_ ;
    return if $value % 3;
    return "$value is a multiple of 3";
}
```

When calling these both flavours of the subroutine, I was expecting to find some consistency between what both `return` in list context:

- a string when the conditional evaluates to true
- nothing (an empty list) when the conditional evaluates to false

But alas, the behaviour was slightly unexpected:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use feature 'say';

my %subs = (
            graceful => sub {
                            my ( $value ) = @_ ;
                            return if $value % 3;
                            return "$value is a multiple of 3";
                        },

              clumsy => sub {
                            my ( $value ) = @_ ;
                            return "$value is a multiple of 3"
                              unless $value % 3;
                        },
           );

for my $name ( keys %subs ) {

    my $sub = $subs{$name};
    say $name;
    my @results = map { $sub->($_) } 1 .. 10;
    p @results;
}
```

***Output***

```
graceful
[
    [0] "3 is a multiple of 3",
    [1] "6 is a multiple of 3",
    [2] "9 is a multiple of 3"
]
clumsy
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] "3 is a multiple of 3",
    [3] 1,
    [4] 2,
    [5] "6 is a multiple of 3",
    [6] 1,
    [7] 2,
    [8] "9 is a multiple of 3",
    [9] 1
]
```

***Question***

The "graceful" flavour behaves as expected, but why is the "clumsy" sub returning back integers when the conditional is false?

Comment: Related [Should a subroutine always return explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761824/should-a-subroutine-always-return-explicitly). I am not sure if this should be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour is consistent with what is documented in [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

> A `return` statement may be used to exit a subroutine, optionally
>   specifying the returned value, which will be evaluated in the
>   appropriate context (list, scalar, or void) depending on the context
>   of the subroutine call. ***If you specify no return value, the subroutine
>   returns an empty list in list context***, the undefined value in scalar
>   context, or nothing in void context. If you return one or more
>   aggregates (arrays and hashes), these will be flattened together into
>   one large indistinguishable list.
>
> If ***no return is found and if the last statement is an expression, its value is returned***. If the last statement is a loop control structure like a `foreach` or a `while` , the returned value is unspecified. The empty sub returns the empty list.

---

**The graceful sub in list context**:

- *True* :  returns the string `"$value is a multiple of 3"` is returned
- *False* : returns an empty list

Which is why there are only three elements in `@results`; something is added to the array only when the conditional evaluates to true.

**The clumsy sub in list context**:

- *True* : returns the string `"$value is a multiple of 3"` is returned. No dramas here.
- *False* : as no explicit `return` is encountered, returns the value of the last expression evaluated , `$value % 3`

So in both cases, the subroutine will return back a value, which is why `@results` has ten items in it.

Comment: Here's a rub for me -- the last "thing" in "clumsy" is `if (not ...)`.  The docs specify behavior for either an "expression" or for "loop control structure" ... so what about `if`, or `not`? It appears that they "don't count", it still returns the last evaluation.  However, this may also happen under "unspecified" -- we get the value here, but in some other case it may be something else.

Comment: See [Statement Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Simple-Statements) in `perlsyn` for `EXPR` examples

Comment: I am asking about what comes _after_ the expression is evaluated -- it's the `unless` that is executed (which should be `not` followed by `if`).  The docs don't seem to specify what happens when the last thing is an `if`.

Comment: @zdim Let me repost the comment here: Interestingly, changing the clumsy sub to `return if not $value % 3` results in the empty string being returned, not the result of the modulus

Comment: Whoa, now that's a discovery (to me). So `unless` behaves differently from `if not`, in a way that has consequences. I don't mean the syntactic differences (one can't do `EXPR for my $var LIST` for example), but the order of processing. It seems from your example that the last thing that is done in `unless EXPR` is in fact the evaluation of the `EXPR`, while in `if (! EXPR)` it seems to be `if`

Comment: @zdim yes, it would seem so. It would make for a pretty interesting Q&A I guess. The difference is that the `not` is considered to be part of `EXPR`, while in `unless` it isn't

Comment: Good point, but still -- then `unless` is only fully equivalent to `if`, and so they are processed differently. That's consequential.

Comment: @zdim should I post the question or will you do it?

Comment: Thanks for asking -- please go ahead and post.

Comment: Thank you for the note, I just came back to my computer.  Will pitch in as soon as I get a minute, I think it's a very interesting question.

Comment: It was my second comment with that _wrong_ statement "_`unless` ... should be `not` followed by `if`_" that triggered the discussion that lead to the other question.  Sorry that I pushed the wrong way.  I still think that it was a good question to ask.  Btw, I also think that my _first_ comment here stands -- the docs indeed don't specify how `if` weighs in this context.  (Probably doesn't matter a bit --  apparently, it "doesn't count" so to say, what makes sense.)

Comment: I came all the way for this *If no return is found and if the last statement is an expression, its value is returned* Thats weird and unexpected!

Answer (score 2):

For last-expression purposes, `foo if bar` and `if (bar) { foo }` are equivalent to `bar and foo`, and similarly unless is equivalent to or.